# C++ - assigning constexpr char * to static char * copies the string ... is it a bug?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Consider the following program. It simply copies a `constexpr const char *` to a `static const char *`. I would expect the pointer to be copied, and be identical. And this is what happens with gcc, clang, and msvc with most options.

However, when using the flag `/Zi` flag instead of `/ZI` with a recent msvc, the assert is triggered. I'm wondering if this is a compiler bug or just undefined behavior.

```
#include <cassert>

constexpr const char *test = "test";

int main()
{
    static const char *a = test;
    assert(a == test);
}
```

Here is a compiler explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/WPz7GPosa. Just changing `/Zi` to `/ZI` in the executor tab makes the assert go away.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: The link seems to be pointing to a different program